# Questions related to group theory

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, normal-subgroups, group-isomorphism, group-homomorphism

If $H$ and $K$ are two normal subgroups of a group $G$, such that $H \subseteq K$, then show that $K/H$ is a normal subgroup of $G/H$.

Here how do I prove that $hk=kh$ because in this question as we know $H$ is normal to $G$ so $hg=gh$ and $K$ is also normal to $G$ so $kg=gk$. And also $H$ is contained in $K$. Which means all $h$ belong to $K$.

Comment: If you think $H$ normal in $G$ means $hg=gh$ then you need to revise the definition of "normal".

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Answer (score 1):

By definition:

\begin{alignat}{2}
K/H \unlhd G/H &\iff &&\forall g\in G,\forall k\in K, \space \space gH(kH)(gH)^{-1}\in K/H \\
&\stackrel{H\unlhd G}{\iff} &&\forall g\in G,\forall k\in K, \space \space gH(kH)(g^{-1}H)\in K/H \\
&\stackrel{H\unlhd K}{\iff} &&\forall g\in G,\forall k\in K, \space \space gkH(g^{-1}H)\in K/H \\
&\stackrel{H\unlhd G}{\iff} &&\forall g\in G,\forall k\in K, \space \space gkg^{-1}H\in K/H \\
\end{alignat}

and the latter holds because $K\unlhd G$.

Answer (score 0):

The kernel of the natural projection $\varphi : G \rightarrow G/K$ contains $H$ because $H \subset K$, therefore it induces a map $\tilde{\varphi} : G/H \rightarrow G/K$ whose kernel is $\mathrm{Ker}{(\varphi)}/H=K/H$. As a kernel, $K/H$ is normal in $G/H$.

However, as said in comments, you should work a little bit more about normal subgroups before considering this proof.